# optimize javascript display style

Tags: javascript

How can I optimize that style.display JavaScript, I don't wanna use "count" variable, it's just a w3school example and I wonder how to optimize it without using "count" variable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

    <p id="demo">JavaScript can hide HTML elements.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick=show()>Click Me!</button>

</body>

<script>
count = 0
function show() {
    if (count%2==0) {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none'
    } else {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.display='block'
    }
    count++;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `classList.toggle`

```js
function show() {

  document.getElementById('demo').classList.toggle('hide')

}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can hide HTML elements.</p>

<button type="button" onclick=show()>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically toggling the div, so you can achieve that by writing in the following way.

```js
function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById('demo').style.display === 'block') {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.display='block'
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can hide HTML elements.</p>

<button type="button" onclick=toggle()>Click Me!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean.

```
<script>
hide = false;
function show() {
    hide = !hide
        if (hide) {
            document.getElementById('demo').style.display = 'none'
        } else {
            document.getElementById('demo').style.display = 'block'
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use extra CSS and non-intrusive Javascript:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
demo.style.display = 'block';

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  demo.style.display = demo.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

```html
<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
<p id="demo">JavaScript can hide HTML elements.</p>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: inline css is never a good idea , it has the highest specificity.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve.